# batch file to delete lines of one text file from another

Tags: file, batch-file

i have two text files- blacklist.txt and complete.txt.
I want a batch file not bash file code.
I want to delete the common lines between the two files.
names in blacklist file should be deleted from complete.txt file
any help ?

Comment: `@for /f "delims=" %A in (black.txt) Do (@Findstr /v /C:"%A" complete.txt > newfile.txt & Copy /y newfile.txt complete.txt)` Use `%%A` in a batch and `%A` when typing at the prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much the code really worked. :)

Comment: It is not working when the blacklist.txt is saved in unicode. only working when it is saved in ANSI. Can I get it to work with unicode file aswell

Comment: `@for /f "delims=" %A in ('type black.txt') Do (@Findstr /v /C:"%A" complete.txt > newfile.txt & Copy /y newfile.txt complete.txt)` We now read the output of the `type` command by enclosing it in `'...'`.

Comment: yup now its working with the unicode blacklist,txt too. But its not matching the unicode characters. One name is in Urdu language and it is not matching and removing it from complete.txt

Comment: Because it will be converted to US DOS/OEM encoding unless your machine is set to Urdu. I really can't help on non western scripts. Is it different if you set your Non Unicode language to Urdu (you'll have to add it first). You can try `find` instead of `findstr`. You can try `CHCP` command 65001 is UTF8. Start CMD with a `/u` switch.

Comment: not just urdu, my complete.txt contains english, urdu, etc languages. can't we just do a string match.

Comment: VBScript is easier for this.

Comment: when I convert unicode file to ANSI, these other language names turns in questionmarks. can I delete them with findstr. I tried type output.txt | findstr /v "?" > complete.txt

Comment: `.*?.*` this handles any line that has a question mark. `?*` handles line of only question marks. `?*\.?*` would handle a filename `?????.?????`. `\ ` is the escape char. See `Findstr /?`.

Comment: What format is your other file. Is it also Unicode?

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr /v /x /g:blacklist.txt complete.txt >outfile.txt
```

should remove all entries in `blacklist` from `complete` to produce `outfile`

Comment: Let me recommend to state the `/L` option to force literal search mode...

Answer (score 1):

This does Unicode input and output. Name it something.vbs.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set BlackFile = Fso.OpenTextFile(Arg(0), 1, False, -1)
Set CompleteFile = Fso.OpenTextFile(Arg(1), 1, False, -1)
Set OutputFile = Fso.CreateTextFile(Arg(2), True, True)
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
Do Until BlackFile.AtEndOfStream
    Line=BlackFile.readline
    Dict.Add Line, ""
Loop
Do Until CompleteFile.AtEndOfStream
    Line=CompleteFile.readline
    If Dict.Exists(Line)
        OutputFile.Writeline Line
    End If
Loop
```

To use at command prompt.

```
C:\folder\something.vbs black.txt complete.txt newfile.txt
```